# How to directly input RGB(A) values in textures in C++/OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I want to dabble in some procedural textures in an OpenGL project, but nothing seems to work. All I need is to input the RGB and maybe A values into an empty texture, instead of loading it from a file. How do I do this, in actual, practical code?

Edit: There is no main code yet, because I have found nothing that works. The current best guess is this:

```
void GenerateTexture()
{
    unsigned char image_data[16] = {0, 0, 150, 255, 125, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 150, 255, 125, 0, 0, 255};
    glGenTextures(1, &tex_obj);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_obj);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
}
```

... implemented like this:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
if (*irrelevant for question*){
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
    glVertex3f (-0.45-cam.pos.val[0], 0.45-cam.pos.val[1], 0.45-cam.pos.val[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f (-0.45-cam.pos.val[0], -0.45-cam.pos.val[1], 0.45-cam.pos.val[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
    glVertex3f (0.45-cam.pos.val[0], -0.45-cam.pos.val[1], 0.45-cam.pos.val[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
    glVertex3f (0.45-cam.pos.val[0], 0.45-cam.pos.val[1], 0.45-cam.pos.val[2]);
}
glEnd ();
```

... but as soon as it is run with more than a 1x1 texture, it just goes clean white.

Comment: Are you trying to generate them in C++? Because from OpenGL's perspectives, it's exactly the same as "loading it from a file", since OpenGL doesn't deal in files. That is, whatever code you're using to upload the data to OpenGL is what you would use. It's merely the source of that data which changes.

Comment: I am generating it in C++, but the first several attempts have given no result. Not even errors....

Comment: @HenryStone Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "but as soon as it is run with more than a 1x1 texture, it just goes clean white." Of course it will, as your texture won't be mipmap-complete if it is bigger than 1x1.

Comment: How do I make it complete, or turn mipmaps off entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an array of data and load it into a texture image:

```cpp
uint8_t image_data[4] = {255, 0, 0, 255}; // red
GLuint tex_obj;
glGenTextures(1, &tex_obj);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_obj);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data);
```